# Why am getting this error in jupyter lab? "AssertionError: wrong color format 'ansiyellow'"

Tags: jupyter-lab, assertion

[image: In this image I have shown you the error.]

I know there is a "." missing while reading csv file in the end. That I have done knowingly just to show you what extra error am getting everytime. The problem is whenever I do any mistake in coding I get this assertionError : wrong color format everytime . can you help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that you are using a recent IPython version (8.0) but do not have the required (recent) pygments version (as per https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/13441). An explicit requirement of pygments>=2.4.0 was added in IPython 8.1. The options are:

- if you have 8.0: either upgrade to the latest IPython or upgrade pygments
- if you have newer IPython: check pygments version and try to upgrade if below 2.4.0

Comment: Thank You , Finally my problem is solved